# Android FacebookSDK Login Webview, No Images

Tags: java, android, facebook, webview, facebook-sdk-3.0

[image]
[image: https://i.imgur.com/CsRpqFg.jpg]

I am trying to set up FacebookSDK in my app. (Added it as a library, so on, so on). I'm not sure why but after logging in, my profile picture and app picture isn't showing up.

The first picture is one where I've manually copied over all source files from facebookSDK and the second is of facebookSDK as a library. I'm not sure where to even begin looking for this bug as it seems that facebook login page is just a webview returned by facebook itself.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try logging in using different test users? Read about it here: [Test Users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users)

See if the problem still exists.